# Creating tableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I am creating custom UITableViewCell with storyboard, I create custom class and drag elements to it, but then I create cell and then it method
runs

```
 cell = [[TestCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
```

cell elements not initialized. Why?

Class with default implementation, in storyboard I have reference to test Label :

```
@interface TestCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *test;
```

I create cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"TestCellIdentifier";

    TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[TestCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

    DetailItem *item = _currentItems[indexPath.row];
    cell.test.text = item.title;
    return cell;
}
```

Problem is that then I create cell, test UILabel is nil.
This happens after segue from first UITableViewController to next

Comment: Have you set the same cell identifier in the Interface builder for the Cell as well ? Do have a check on it.

Comment: In Storyboard, did you set your cell's class as "testCell" ?

Comment: Problem is that then I create cell, test label is nil

Comment: Use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and you will get the cell designed using prototype cells with all elements initialised. Read up on `initWithCoder:` and how cell reuse and nibs work.

Comment: @zfzdfsdfsdfsdfsd From your question `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *test;` the property is having `strong` pointer but it should be weak if it is attached to `storyboard`. check everything again by deleting the connection of your cell inner elements and re-add them to your cell class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1, you can set a breakpoint in the if statement:

```
 if (!cell)
    {
=>        cell = [[TestCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
```

**The breakpoint should never be triggered. Since you use Storyboard and Cell reuse identifier set correct**

If Step1 passed, check Step2

Step2, check in the storyboard if you have connected the "test" UILabel from Storyboard to your TestCell

Answer (score 0):

You have to type caste like

```
 TestCell *cell1 = (TestCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```